# Differentiability at a point $x$ with $f$ differentiable in $\mathbb R\backslash\{x\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a real function that satisfies:

1. $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is differentiable at $x$ for $x\neq x_0$.
2. There is a full-measure set $T$ such that for any sequence $t_n\in T$ with $t_n\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} x_0$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f^\prime (t_n) = c$.
3. $f$ is non-decreasing

I'm trying to show that **$\mathbf{f}$ must also be differentiable at $\mathbf{x_0}$.**

My idea is that if there is some sequence $x_n$ with $x_n\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} x_0$ and  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_0)} {x_n-x_0} \neq c$ then I can approximate the $x_n$ and $x_0$ with points in $T$ but I have to be careful with the choice of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ in approximation because we have two limits here (the derivative itself and the limit of the derivatives). I'm not sure if this would work because it seems that I would need to change the order of limits. Besides, in real analysis, there are some many pathological cases that perhaps there is even a counter-example. Any suggestions on how to attack this problem?

Comment: As the accept  answer shows we must also have $f$ continuous. The accept answer uses Theorem 7.15 (Rudin, Real & Complex Analysis, 3rd ed, p. 143).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you let $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$ you get a counterexample. The result you want requires that you assume that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Assuming that, there's probably a more elementary proof than the following simple but not quite so elementary proof:

Say $x_0=0$ for convenience. Subtract a constant so $f(-1)=0$.

Now since $f$ is continuous at $0$ and differentiable elsewhere it is continuous. So there exists a finite measure $\mu$ on $[-1,1]$ such that $$f(x)=\mu([-1,x])\quad(x\in[-1,1]).$$

Now $\mu=\mu_a+\mu_s$ where $\mu_a$ is absolutely continuous and $\mu_s$ is singular (wrt Lebesgue measure). We must have $\mu_s([-1,1]\setminus\{0\})=0,$ since otherwise there would exist $x\ne0$ such that $f$ was not differentiable at $x$. And $\mu_s(\{0\})=0$ since $f$ is continuous at $0$.

So $\mu_s=0$, which says that $f$ is absolutely continuous. In particular, $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac1x\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt,$$and now the assumption about $f'$ tending to $c$ on a set of full measure shows that $f'(0)=c$.

Comment: well, you don't need $\mu$. Since $f'$ is bounded near $x_0$, $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on a neighborhood of $x_0$, thus absolutely continuous.

Comment: @user251257 Exactly how does it follow that $f$ is Lipschitz? Can't use fundamental theorem of calculus since we don't know $f$ is absolutely continuous. Mean value theorem is at least problematic since we don't know that $f'$ is bounded near $x_0$, just on a set of full measure. Which is enough. _Why_ is it enough, exactly? You may well be right - I don't see it offhhand...

Comment: you are right. I wrote the comment too fast. I will think about it.

Comment: @user251257 While you're thinking, keep the "Cantor function" in mind. Nondecreasing, continuous, $f'=0$ almost everywhere, not constant. Not a counterexample to the theorem because it's not differentiable, but a counterexample to various wrong proofs of the theorem...

Comment: Thanks David! Yes $f$ is continuous in my original problem. Do you wish to be acknowledge by name in the paper?

Comment: I suppose that would be appropriate, yes. (Feel free to send money instead. heh-heh)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So you didn't use monotonicity (or it is hidden somewhere in (implicit) assumption on $\mu$)? I guess Lebesgue decomposition is valid for signed measures too.

Comment: @A.G. I said $\mu$ is a measure, meaning $\mu\ge0$, which uses monotonicity. There's no doubt an argument for $f$ of bounded variation, using signed measures. It seems possible it would be at least slightly trickier at one spot. I used the fact that if $\mu_s\ge0$ is singular (and nonzero) there exists $x$ with $1/h\mu_s([x,x+h])\to\infty$. This implies immediatey that $f$ is not differentiable at $x$, _because_ $f$ is non-decreasing. Various bits of cancellation one would have to worry about for functions of bounded variation...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich "We must have $\mu_s([−1,1]\backslash\{0\})=0$, since otherwise there would exist $x\neq 0$ such that $f$ was not differentiable at $x$". Is this obvious? Or do I need something like the answer to this question I posted back in Apri:l http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257562/non-decreasing-and-everywhere-differentiable-on-0-1-implies-absolutelly-cont

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I'm not sending money but ordered a copy of "Complex Made Simple" ;-)

Comment: @SergioParreiras Probably not "obvious" unless you know a certain theorem. In general define $D\mu(x)=\lim_{h\to0}(1/h)\mu([x,x+h])$, when the limit exists. If $\mu_s\ge0$ is singular then it's a theorem (in Rudin and in Folland) that $D\mu_s=+\infty$ a.e.[$\mu_s$]. In particular this happens at at least one point $x$ if $\mu_s\ne0$. Now since $\mu_a\ge0$ it follows that $f(x+h)-f(x)\ge\mu_s([x,x+h])$, and hence $f'(x)=+\infty$, contradiction.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I found a proof that $f$ is AC in a neighborhood of $x_0$, without using decomposition. However it isn't really shorter. Essentially, a differentiable function has Lusin N property. http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-105-prev.pdf

Comment: @user251257 "essentially"?? Are you saying a differentiable function  must have the Lusin N property or not? If yes: How do you prove that? I find it very hard to believe. If no: What _are_ you saying? (Yes, the theorem in that pdf says that _if_ our function has Lusin N then it's AC.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: in that pdf, corollary 3.14 says that a differentiable function has the Lusin N property. Since $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0$ only, it has also the Lusin N property. Thus, $f$ is (locally) AC.

Comment: @user251257 Oh - missed that, sorry. Yes, that wraps it up. (Although I agree that, as you said, it's not really shorter. The argument I gave uses "that measure". But it only uses stuff "everybody knows". It's possible that everybody knows about that Lusin N thing, but if so I'm nobody. Heh.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I thought it would be more elementary... too bad.