# Functions with non-zero derivative sending sets of positive measure to sets of positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For the purposes of this question, assume that when "measure" is mentioned, we refer to the Lebesgue measure.

Suppose I have a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{df}{dx}$ is non-zero at every point. Is it then the case that for any set of positive measure $X$, $f(X)$ also has positive measure? If not, what precondition is required for this to be the case.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I would be satisfied with an answer for the case: $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: There are a couple of little technicalities that I am not sure of, but I think that the basic argument should follow from Darboux. It follows from Darboux's theorem that we may assume that $f'$ is positive (or negative, resp.) on $\Bbb R$, from which it follows that $f$ is increasing (or decreasing, resp.).  But then $f(a) < f(b)$ (or $f(a) > f(b)$, resp.) for any $a<b$, from which we can conclude that $\mu(f([a,b])) = |f(b)-f(a)|$. So non-degenerate intervals are sent to non-degenerate intervals.  I think that you ought to be able to finish the argument via some kind of appeal to regularity.

Comment: This argument does assumes, however, that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ (not just almost all $x$), but this seems to be implied by the hypothesis that $f'(x) \ne 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I'm with you up until the end. The case that is unclear to me are when the positive-measure set is something that contains no positive length intervals. For example, the intersection of [a,b] with the irrationals. I assume that this is where the regularity comes into play, but I'm not familiar enough with the notion to know for sure. Is there any chance you could shed some light on this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.   By Darboux's theorem, $f'$ must have constant sign, so $f$ is monotone.  It follows that $f$ is locally absolutely continuous (see [Non-decreasing and everywhere differentiable on $[0,1]$ implies absolutelly continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257562/non-decreasing-and-everywhere-differentiable-on-0-1-implies-absolutelly-cont)), and so for any interval $I$, $$\mu(f(I))=\int_I |f'|.$$  Both sides of this equation are measures when considered as functions of $I$ (here we use the fact that $f$ is injective so $f(\cdot)$ preserves disjointness of sets), and it follows that the two sides are equal for all Borel sets as well: for any Borel set $X$, $$\mu(f(X))=\int_X|f'|.$$  If $X$ has positive measure, then the integral on the right is positive since $f'$ is always nonzero, so $\mu(f(X))>0$.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose this also holds for open intervals by simply taking a suitably large sub-interval that is closed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this".  I'm not assuming any interval is closed here.  In any case, everything in this question is local, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more verbose. The preconditions for Darboux's theorem stated that $I$ should be a closed interval, which was the motivation behind the followup question. The question you linked also used a closed interval as an example, so I just wanted to make sure that everything still held when talking about open intervals.

Comment: I guess maybe I should have said "locally absolutely continuous", since it seems that definitions of absolute continuity on non-compact intervals vary and may be stronger than what I am asserting here.

Comment: Right, everything here is local (we only need all these statements to hold in some neighborhood of every point), so we can freely use theorems that are stated only for closed intervals.

Comment: Note also that the end result in the case when $f$ is defined on an arbitrary interval follows immediately from the case where $f$ is defined on a compact interval, since any interval can be written as a countable union of compact intervals.